# Fluent NHibernate - Ignore Primary Key Convention for 1 mapping file

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

All my tables have an integer column as an Id - Primary Key

Except one

```
        instance.CustomType<int>();
        instance.GeneratedBy.Custom<global::NHibernate.Id.IdentityGenerator>();
        instance.UnsavedValue("0");
```

Is there a way to ignore the primary key convention for this one mapping file?

```
          mapping.Id(a => a.Id, "RoleName").GeneratedBy.Assigned();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override it.  Although it looks like you are try to use a mixture of both Fluent NH Automapping and mapping by code which I'm not sure that it will work in this case.  I would override it like this:

```
AutoMap.AssemblyOf<Role>().Override<Role>(map =>
{
    map.Id(x => x.Id, "RoleName")
        .CustomType<int>()
        .GeneratedBy.Identity()
        .UnsavedValue("0");
});
```

I took the basic idea from: https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Auto-mapping